# Interceptor does not Exist

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3.0

[image: **THis is the error message i get when i try creating a new product can someone kindly assist me**]

Hello guys , I am currently on magento version 2.3.0 and I am getting this error whenever I try adding a product in my admin panel.
Can someone kindly assist me .

After running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

I get this error when loading my admin panel.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\module-backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index.php(39): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Backend...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(108): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index->execute() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(159): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRe in C:\xampp\htdocs\providencecameras\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php on line 27
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have getting interceptor issue because Di compile is not working.

And di compile is not working as `Plazathemes_BannerSliders` have some issue.So, first Disable the `Plazathemes_BannerdSlider` Then Do the di compile.I guess that it will resolve your issue.